# Fresh Laravel 5 shows 500 Internal Server Error no matter what (OS X, Apache)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-5

My setup is OS X Yosemite, default Apache and PHP 5.6.

Vhost is set correctly, I have two other apps running ok:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin polar
   ServerName lara5.com
   ServerAlias lara5.com
   DocumentRoot "/Users/polar/Sites/lara5/public"
   ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host2.example.com-error_log"
   CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host2.example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Hosts file is OK.

I've set the permissions to 777 to the whole project folder, still nothing.

If I remove .htaccess, the splash screen shows for the url lara5.com but the /home route returns 404.

I have tried both .htaccess (inside /public, ofc) Laravel provides, none of them work, 500 doesn't matter which route I access.

Default:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Other one from the docs:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Any ideas?
 Thanks.

Comment: For any 500 error, first place to check is Apache's `error.log` file.

Comment: With no .htaccess, no errors on the log, with the first one:  [Wed Feb 04 16:34:46.965630 2015] [core:alert] [pid 1073] [client 127.0.0.1:53871] /Users/polar/Sites/lara5/public/.htaccess: Options not allowed here

Comment: ok comment out `Options +FollowSymLinks` line and retest

Comment: Yeah, that worked. Should this be reported/merged to the laravel project? Thank you.

Comment: Also, I think you should post up an answer so I can check it as correct if anyone else comes across this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translating comment into an answer to help out anyone else comes across this problem.

Based on your snippet from `error.log` it seems that `Options` directive isn't allowed in your `.htaccess`.

You can fix this error by commenting any line in your `.htaccess` starting from:

```
Options
```

---

To enable use of `Options` in `.htaccess` use:

```
Options All
```

in your Apace config's `<Directory>` section of your `DocumentRoot`.